# how to assign the values to a string array directly taken from input using bufferedreader?

Tags: java, arrays, string, bufferedreader

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in);
    String[] a = new String[]{br.readLine().split("\\s")};
}
```

I'm getting errors here. Is there any direct way to convert the line into array of strings?

Comment: `.split()` returns a String array, so it is not necessary to instantiate one yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`split` returns an `array` of strings so you can simply initialize `a` as:

```
String[] a = br.readLine().split("\\s");
```

`String[] myArray = new String[] {...}` is what is known as an [array literal](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/arrays-in-java/), and the values need to be known before the code runs.